# Sharepoint Cracl rules - Exclude everything except one list

Tags: sharepoint, web-crawler

I have a simple question but the solution seems rather awkward or maybe I am missing something.

I have a bunch of lists and document libraries in my Sharepoint site and I would like to exclude everything from my search except all the items from one particular list.
So me trying to be smart created some Crawl Rules in the following order:

```
1. http://domain/en/Lists/ListName/* - Include<br />
2. http://* - Exclude<br />
```

I assume the order of the rules are being respected by the crawl engine and that the first match is the final match?